# How to get source of packages in Manjaro

Tags: source, manjaro

I am trying to study the source code of popular packages as a learning method.
 I am running Manjaro 0.8.13, and it says it is based on Arch Linux. I've used Arch before, so I know it has the ABS to get source code.

So, I looked for a way to use it on Manjaro but I didn't find anything similar other than the `buildtree` program from the `manjaro-tools` package.

I ran: `buildtree -as` to sync, and I found some `*.set`-patterned files but I didn't know what to do with them.

[This is the documentation of `manjaro-tools`](https://github.com/manjaro/manjaro-tools).

Comment: Most of it is on SourceForge. So you might want to ask another question like... *How long until SourceForge works again?*

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: @mikeserv: I mean: Can't I even download the source code that is not hosted on SourceForge ? Or is the problem being the non-availability of ABS on Manjaro ? _(sorry if my earlier comment wasn't clear, I deleted it)_.

Comment: Sure, I guess. If you can find it, download it. I only knew about the sf repo.

Answer (score 1):

The sources for all [Manjaro](https://github.com/manjaro) packages can be found on their github site

Comment: The github site is archived.  Everything is on their gitlab site now, https://gitlab.manjaro.org/packages  However, some packages aren't here.  E.g., ffmpeg isn't in extra, but it is available for Manjaro.  I don't know where one is supposed to find these packages.